# about another way to send ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my code.

```
 function ajax() {
   var ajaxRequest;
   try {
     ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   catch (e) {
     try {
       ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
     }
     catch (e) {
       try {
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
       catch (e) {
         alert("Your browser broke!");
         return false;
       }
     }
   }

   return ajaxRequest;
 }

 var ajax = ajax();
 ajax.Message = function (method, l) {
   ajax.open(method, url, false);
   ajax.send();
   ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {}
   }
 }
```

Every time I want to send a request, I need to use this function, but when I look the code in Youtube, or Twitter, I see that they don't work like this.

Is there a short way to send AJAX? I mean only using JavaScript, without using jQuery.

Comment: Nobody is going to read that dense code. Consider reformatting it for human consumption.

Comment: jQuery is only JavaScript. Yes it uses this method - wrapped in one huge function. What's wrong with that?

Comment: `ajax = ajax()` is very bad style (unless you do it right and return functions).

Comment: 1.Sorry for my English I dont speak english.
2.This is not my question,my question is I use this function a lot
this is reasonable?Because anoter sites not uses in this function so how they work?

Comment: They use this or jQuery which is also this under the covers

Comment: So why I dont see the url each time they call this function?
Because when I use this I write the url.

Comment: @user1758424 Because they usually stay away from such URLs. Why bother specifying a URL each time you want to show a favourites widget? Isn't it better to just: `widgets.refresh('favourites');`? Of course, *somewhere* they do use such URLs, probably something builds the URL itself given input such as what to do and with what parameters. If you really wanted to see said URLs, open up your web browser tools (Firebug, Web Dev Tools, etc) and monitor Network tab for connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other sites use more or less what you posted or jQuery which is more or less what you posted under the covers.

You want the above shorter?

http://anthologyoi.com/dev/short-ajax-script.html

```
function a(l,d,u){try{r = new XMLHttpRequest();}catch(e){try {r = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');}catch(e){r = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');}} if(r){r.onreadystatechange = function() {if (r.readyState == 4 && r.status == 200){document.getElementById(u).innerHTML = r.responseText;}} r.open('GET', l+'?'+d, true);r.send(d);}}
```

Comment: @user1758424 An uglifier/minifier is only half of the story. The rest lies in not repeating code, such as the one for connecting.